# ActionLink jQuery parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application.

I have a dropdownbox with a list of “reports”. Next to the dropdown, I have two ActionLink. One that says “*Add new report*” and the other one say “*Edit report*”.

The “*Add new report*” link, is pretty straightforward … it calls a ViewResult in my Controller and returns a `new View()`. Great! this works no problem!

The “*Edit report*” link is a bit trickier since I wish to pass the selected ID of the item currently selected inside the dropdown to the ActionLink.

I've found an article that shows me how to AJAXify my ActionLink but I’m doing something wrong…

Here is the ActionLink in the View for the “Edit” link:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Edit report", "EditReport", "Report", null, new { id = "edit" })%>
```

Here is the jQuery click event to handle the “click”

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: '<%=Url.Action("EditReport")%>',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { reportId: $('select[name="ReportId"] option:selected').val() },
     success: function(result) {
          //alert("succes");
     },
     error: function() {
          alert("error");
     }
     });
   return false;
});
```

Here is the method in the Controller:

```
public ViewResult EditReport(int reportId)
{
      return View("EditReport");
}
```

When placing a breakpoint in the Controller’s method, it gets hit and the parameter “*reportId*” is correctly passed…but the rest of the code (return View() portion) does not seem to work because inside the jQuery click event, I have a “return false”.

When removing the “return false” inside the click event, the breakpoint no longer gets hit. Thus, I can't go to my “EditReport” view…

What am I missing/not understanding here?

Also … is there a better/nicer/cleaner approach to achieve my task without having to use an AJAX call?

Comment: have you tried on your action to return json or string instead of view?

Comment: Well…the thing is that I wish to show a different (“EditReport”) view which will be strongly typed. That view will have a form allowing the user to edit the report information. Correct me if I’m wrong but, returning json won’t redirect me to another view correct? Perhaps my entire approach is wrong.

Comment: You don't have to use ajax to redirect user to other view, I believe the purpose of ajax to update page content without reloading the entire page.

Comment: I agree with you, ajax is usually used to update parts of the pages without a full reload. And since I wish to show a different View() ajax *seems* of no use to me *BUT* how can I pass the selected ID (of the item in my dropdown) as a parameter to my ActionLink? Hence why I figured the only way was with ajax…unless of course, there’s a different approach.

Comment: Ok I found a way! I'll post the reply tomorrow since I can't answer my own post :-( 
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, since I now can post the answer here it is (if anyone is interested):

First, I needed to modify the *ActionLink* and put in a ***predefined*** value for the parameter which will be replaced once the link is clicked.

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Edit report", "EditReport", "Report", new { reportId="xxx"}, new { id = "edit" })%>
```

Second, modify the jQuery click event:

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
    //Get the id of the selected item in dropdown
    var id = $('select[name="ReportId"] option:selected').val();

    //Replace the predifined QueryString param "xxx" with the "id"
    this.href = this.href.replace("xxx", id);
});
```

Nothing changes in the *Controller*’s method…it stays the same:

```
public ViewResult EditReport(int reportId)
{
  //Fix me...
   return View("EditReport");
}
```

Comment: How can I do this when I have multiple parameters? Seems like there is no way to replace multiple values at once with `href.replace` or in my case `url.replace`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, provided you have configured a route path for **ControllerName/EditReports/{ReportId}**

```
$("#edit").click(function() {
      window.location.href = '<%=Url.Action("EditReport")%>' +'/'+ $('select[name="ReportId"] option:selected').val();
      return false;
 });
```