# Modifying ajax.ActionLink in mvc3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have got this link:

```
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { deleteID = menu.MenuID.ToString(), unDelete = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = menu.MenuID.ToString() }, new { id = menu.MenuID.ToString() })
```

When it is pressed, I want to change the value of undelete to 0. But I dont know how
to change the value from the action method. Here is my action method:

```
     public ActionResult Delete(string deleteID, int unDelete)
    {
        _gMenus.DeleteTopic(int.Parse(deleteID), unDelete); 
        return Content("Undelete");
    }
```

I could set the content/text of the link but not the attribute, is there a way to change
the attribute.
And also, I do deletions with ajax (by Get and not post) is it unsafe!?!

**UPDATE:**

```
<a class="deleteLink" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#1" href="/Admin/Delete?deleteID=1&amp;unDelete=1" id="1">Delete</a>
```

I need unDelete to be replaced to 0

I tried to do something like this:

```
    alert(
$(".deleteLink").attr("href", "/Admin/Delete?deleteID=1&amp;unDelete=0").attr()
);
```

But no message appears :(

Answer (score 0):

when I searched about this question I found a the following solution. But I could not try to verify the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840291/actionlink-jquery-parameter)

According to that you can use jQuery to replace the property

```
$("#IdOfActionLink").click(function() {
    
    this.href = this.href.replace("1", "0");
});
```

This has issues I guess like replacing all "1" with "0" but hope this helps you to get an idea

Regards

Comment: hmmm..that ruins my logic a bit..cause it means that  i have to abandon the action logic

Comment: yes, but still you can do a Ajax call to your Action in controller within the click event.

Comment: it doesnt replace the url variable..look at the update to see how it looks like