# change the id of an actionlink when the value of my dropdown changes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, actionlink

I am creating a MVC 3 application and I am trying create a dropdownlist with jQuery using a .change event. I would like the page body to be blank and when the dropdownlist changes I would like links(actionlinks) to appear and to add the Id or value of the dropdown to the actionlink and another dropdownlist.

if anyone can help me or give some advice with this I would grateful.

Edited Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#DivName').hide();
         $("#Dropdownname").change(function () {
             $('#DivName').show();

             var result = $('#Dropdownname').val();


             { $("#OldId").attr('id', result); });

         });
     });
```

My ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action", null, new { id = "OldId" })
```

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post some of your html, an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could put them with a div and .show(); or .hide(); depending on what you wanted to show for example:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.actionLinksdiv').hide();
      $(".dropdownclassname").click(function () {
           $('.actionLinksdiv').show();

         });    
   });
```

To change an id in jquery

```
$("#oldId").attr('id', 'newId');
```

or to add an attribute:

```
$('#oldId').attr('value','newValue');
```

If this isn't what your looking foir maybe post a code example to get some help.

Comment: Hi Anna, thank you for your response.

I have got the div to hide and show etc to work which is good. but how do I add the #oldId to the actionLink?

thanks again for the help

Comment: Hi Adrian sorry just seen this i ve been on holiday have you solved it?

Comment: Hi Anna, no I didn't manage to :( if you have any other suggestions i would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hi Adrian I think you could use something similar to the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840291/actionlink-jquery-parameter

Comment: Thank you very much Anna, I will have a look into this :)